# Form not submitting Select options and I get a blank screen and no error in error log PHP/SQL

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, insert-into

Hi I have a form that i am trying to insert into a database but when i fill it in it redirects to the action page where i am met with a blank screen and no error in my log.

None of my select options are inserting into the database, but all the other fields are?

This is my form I have removed all the classes to make it somewhat easier to read:

```
<form action="ticket-submit.php" method="post">
<div>
    <label>Department<span class="required">*</span></label>
    <div>
        <select required>
            <option value="">Choose option</option>
            <option name="Department">1</option>
            <option name="Department">2</option>
            <option name="Department">3</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>


<?php   
    $getTicketCategory = "SELECT * FROM po_ticket_category";
    $queryTicketCategory = sqlsrv_query($sapconn2, $getTicketCategory);
?>

<div>
    <label>Categorys<span class="required">*</span></label>
    <div>
        <select required>
            <option value="">Choose option</option>
            <?php while($ticketCategory = sqlsrv_fetch_array($queryTicketCategory, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) : ?>
                <option name="Category"><?php echo $ticketCategory['Category']; ?></option>
            <?php endwhile; ?>

        </select>
    </div>
</div>

<?php   
    $getTicketPriority = "SELECT * FROM po_ticket_priority";
    $queryTicketPriority = sqlsrv_query($sapconn2, $getTicketPriority);
?>

<div>
    <label>Priority<span class="required">*</span></label>
    <div>
        <select required>
            <option value="">Choose option</option>
            <?php while($ticketPriority = sqlsrv_fetch_array($queryTicketPriority, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) : ?>
                <option name="PriorityLevel"><?php echo $ticketPriority['PriorityLevel']; ?></option>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <label for="Subject">Subject<span class="required">*</span></label>
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="Subject" id="Subject" placeholder="Subject" required>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <label for="Description">Description<span class="required">*</span></label>
    <div>
        <textarea name="Description" id="Description" rows="3" placeholder='Whats your issue...' required></textarea>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <div>
        <button type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="1">Submit Ticket</button>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

This is my submit code(ticket-submit.php):

```
<?php 

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$userName = (isset($user['userName']) && !empty($user['userName']))?$user['userName'] : NULL;
$department = (isset($_POST['Department']) && !empty($_POST['Department']))?$_POST['Department'] : NULL;
$category = (isset($_POST['Category']) && !empty($_POST['Category']))?$_POST['Category'] : NULL;
$priority = (isset($_POST['PriorityLevel']) && !empty($_POST['PriorityLevel']))?$_POST['PriorityLevel'] : NULL;
$subject = (isset($_POST['Subject']) && !empty($_POST['Subject']))?$_POST['Subject'] : NULL;
$description = (isset($_POST['Description']) && !empty($_POST['Description']))?$_POST['Description'] : NULL;

$query = "INSERT INTO po_ticket_ticket (UserName, DepartmentID, Category, PriorityLevel, Subject, Description, TicketCreated) 
                             VALUES ('$userName', '$department','$category', '$priority', '$subject', '$description', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
                ";
$stmt = sqlsrv_prepare($sapconn2, $query);
sqlsrv_execute($stmt);   
return $stmt;

}
?>
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: You have left your code exposed. You're wide open for SQL Injection there.

Comment: I am aware, but this is just a small personal project for learning so that isn't an issue in this case.

Comment: I appreciate that you're learning but learn the correct way and bind your params. I'm not stating this to be an ass, it's constructive criticism.

Comment: I get that, so any chance you could show me an example of my code set up correctly? - if you have time...

Comment: can you write echo $stmt;instead of return $stmt; ?

Comment: @K D that helped!, I now actually get my page submit message but still submits the row with out the select values :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do not use "name" tag with  use with .. and also there is no value tag with all options, add values with all options...

your dropdown should be something like this

```
<select name="Department" >
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

and to avaid blank page redirect to some html page after query execution..

Comment: Thanks for your input, but i think you may have misunderstood, the page inst suppose to be blank, it should say form submitted etc.

Comment: then  do if(sqlsrv_execute($stmt) ){echo "Data submitted successfully";}